# Web или Dev?

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, продвинутые юзвери. Мой вопрос не очень понятный и совсем неправильный, но всё же. Что лучше выбрать Dev под Шиндовс (такие языки как C#, C++, Delphi) или пойти всторону Web изучая php, JS? Я отлично знаю компьютер на уровне юзера. Что лучше выбрать? Какая из областей более предприимчива? Если Вы выбрали что-то из этого, то почему, какие языки следует изучать? Повторюсь: вопрос не самый корректный.

Comment: Не могли бы вы пояснить нубу, в чем разница между "**Dev**" и "**Web**"?

Comment: > (такие языки как C#, C++, Delphi) 

------

> php, JS?

Другие языки не существуют?

Comment: @Deonis: девелопер и вебелопер, вестимо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно, если я правильно понял, ТС хочет понять, что сейчас более востребованно - разработка прикладных приложений или веб-разработка. Сейчас - это одинаково востребованно (с учетом таких факторов, как конкуренция на рынке вакансий, место проживания ТС и прочее).

Более предприимчиво, на начальном уровне (а как я понял, у ТС в плане девелопмента именно начальный уровень), учиться **программировать**, то есть получать базис, а не распыляться под конкретное "я хочу писать сайты и больше ничего".

По поводу языков - нельзя ответить на этот вопрос, так как при достаточном уровне знаний и достаточной любви к костылям можно практически на любом языке написать практически любую вещь.

Comment: >Более предприимчиво, на начальном уровне ... учиться программировать

+1. А то ведь реально думают некоторые люди, что учить нужно языки, а не учиться рограммировать

Answer (score 1):

Ну что вы набросились на парня ;-), таких вопросов очень много задается в интернете. Обилие информации породило очень важную проблему - разобраться в этом обилии, не потеряться и вычленить нужное и полезное. Не всем это сразу под силу.

Я бы порекомендовал автору не гнаться за скорым успехом, осваивая PHP, скажем, по низкопробным сайтам, написанных такими же, если не хуже, самоучками. Чисто мое имхо, но пойдя таким путем возможно наступит день, когда отсутствие системных знаний, дефицит математических инструментов, банальное непонимание того "как оно работает" приведет к тому, что автор перестанет развиваться в профессиональном плане, превратясь в того, кого иронично называют "быдлокодером" или "говонокодером".

Когда наберется критическая масса таких "спецов" - "наколеночные" отрывочные знания перестанут высоко котироваться, конкуренция будет расти. Если даже этот момент еще далек - не думаю, что Вы хотите стать таким "спецом".

Специалисты в своем деле всегда ценятся, хоть и не всегда достойно оплачиваются. Но в программировании это немного не так и став специалистов хоть в "Web" хоть в "Dev" вы будете востребованы и успешны. Ищите то, что Вам по душе, но не забывайте, что каждое дерево должно иметь корни.

Comment: Золотые слова